# how to make preloader run till js function complete execution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, preloader

I'am trying to run `preloader` till another JavaScript-function completes execution and then stop

I tried to use following

```
function myfunctionstart()
{
$.preloader.start();
.....
.....
.....
.....
.....
.....
.....
.....
.....
.....
.....
.....
.....
$.preloader.stop();
}
```

but this does not works..
`preloader`  either not starting or if started it does not get stopped automatically

Comment: Can you post the full code?

Comment: jQuery.when(), it will return a resolved Promise. you can read about it here https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

Comment: there are many  ```for loops```  at the position of .... in above code, that's it @Emanuele

Comment: maybe in the code inside there is some async function? Or some Promise?

Comment: no its just pure for loops in here that sets the value to the text-boxes from array elements@Emanuele